# gradlew.bat installDebug error while runing react-native code on device

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Whenever I create new project in react native it works fine and runs on android device but when I install "React Navigation 3.x" library in my react native app and try to build it on my device I got the following error

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:622:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:640:13)
at runOnAllDevices (E:\ReactNative\awesomeproject\node_modules\react-
local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
at buildAndRun (E:\ReactNative\awesomeproject\node_modules\react-nati
l-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
at isPackagerRunning.then.result (E:\ReactNative\awesomeproject\node_
\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
```

Comment: It looks like there are somethings missing from the error message. Have you followed the full instructions for installing `react-navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html ?

Comment: yes i followed all the instructions

Comment: react-navigation , react native guesture handler, and after that linking and then going into to MainActivity.java and adding the java imports and overrided method,

you should run it!

Comment: if error still persists then try gradle cleaning . like .  cd andorid && ./gradlew clean and ReRun

Answer (score 1):

Go inside your android directory and use this `./gradlew clean`, after this you will see an error about you are missing the sdk path. Inside the android directory create a new file `local.properties` and write down there the sdk path, Windows: `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\YOU_USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk` the same thing for MAC with a different path (check the path with android studio)